# Are NVIDIA's GPUs big-endian or little-endian?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu, endianness

I need to do a lot of bit-wise operations on GPUs, but cannot find any information regarding whether NVIDIA GPU hardware is big or little-endian.

Comment: What impact would endianness have on bitwise operations in C? Should be none.

Comment: @modifiable lvalue: Your statement is correct as long as there isnt any pointer aliasing there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/366773/cuda-programming-and-performance/endian-mode-of-the-device/post/2630674/#2630674

> All of the supported CUDA platforms use little-endian CPUs, and cudaMemcpy() can copy data structures to the device without knowing the data format, so I would assume the GPU is also little-endian. The GPU might support both big and little endian execution (as some CPUs also do this) as a hedge against future CUDA platforms being big endian.
>
> My guess is the answer has to be either "little-endian" or "both".

Comment: So, is this presumption known to be valid?

Answer (score 18):

**NVIDIA GPUs are little-endian**, per [the Hardware Implementation section of the CUDA guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#hardware-implementation).

Comment: Why the downvote? This has a reference to an authoritative source. The other answer is a guess from an unknown person on a bulletin board.